# how to stop loop in Yuotube Api , 'loop': 0 is not working

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am working on Youtube player API , want to stop the video to play in loop , but it is not working. is there any way to perform this?
Here is my sample code

```js
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player("ytplayer", {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    videoId: "M7lc1UVf-VE",
    playerVars: {
      autoplay: 1,
      showinfo: 0,
      autohide: 1,
      loop: 0,
      controls: 1,
      modestbranding: 1,
      vq: "hd1080",
    },
    events: {
      onReady: onPlayerReady,
      onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange,
    },
  })
}
```